# Oauth on android using signpost library

Tags: android, oauth, signpost

I try since a few days to connect one of my android app to an oauth service. I have found a few really good articles like http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/04/12/oauth-android-google-apis-client-library-java/ or marakana.com/forums/android/examples/312.html but even with those papers I can't manage to make It work.

Well, here is my current code packaged in a tar archive : http://braindead.fr/oauth-warrior.tar.gz

So the problem is that each time I attempt to retrieve an access token I got an OAuthCommunicationException (respectively line 26 and 39 of OAUthTokenValidator.java) after user validation on oauth server and url callback.

I anybody know why signopost/oauth does not accept to make this last call I'll be really grateful :)

Sincerely, Daroth

Answer (score 1):

this might be a bit late to answer, but still.. for folks still searching:

- check your menu->settings->date/time, sometimes an emulator's timezone won't match the real timezone. thus, the server denies it. they usually have a 3-10 minute variance.
- check your manifest for INTERNET permission ;)

another tip: not many elder wizards would unpack a tar from an unknown source.. you should use a pastebin service, or an open git/svn/hg repo.